# How append date info to a time column on read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file in the following format

```
00:05:00;300;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;18.1;3.8;2.3
00:05:00;300;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;16.7;3.8;2.3
00:05:00;300;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;17.387;3.8;2.3
00:05:00;300;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;16.2;3.8;2.3
```

I'm reading the data in the following way;

```py
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", decimal=".", skiprows=7, header=None)
```

My filename is `180619.csv` where `180619` is the date. I'd like to append the date to time column which is read as Object type and make it datetime64 object for future searches.

Regards,

Comment: how does this work? `df[0]=pd.to_datetime(filename.split('\\')[-1][:-4]+' '+ df[0])` ?? replace 0 with the column name for time you have

Comment: Nope. `ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '180617 Info')` is thrown.

Comment: show the code that is throwing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the filename into a suiteable prefix that you can prepend to `df[0]` and then convert the column to datetime using `pd.to_datetime(df[0])` - as @anky_91 hinted at:

**Create file**

```
filename = "180619.txt"
with open(filename, "w") as f: 
    f.write("""
00:05:00;300;3;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;18.1;3.8;2.3
00:05:00;300;7;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;16.7;3.8;2.3
00:05:00;300;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;17.387;3.8;2.3
00:05:00;300;2;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;16.2;3.8;2.3
""")
```

**Process file:**

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "180619.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", decimal=".", skiprows=1, header=None)

print(df)

# yymmdd
fn = filename.split(".")[0]

# 3.6 f-string, use "20{}/{}/{} ".format(fn[:2],fn[2:4],fn[4:]) if f-string not available
fn = f"20{fn[:2]}/{fn[2:4]}/{fn[4:]} " 

df[0] = fn+df[0]
print(df)

df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
print(df)
```

**Outputs:**

```
# data
         0    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12      13   14   15
0  00:05:00  300   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  18.100  3.8  2.3
1  00:05:00  300   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  16.700  3.8  2.3
2  00:05:00  300   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  17.387  3.8  2.3
3  00:05:00  300   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  16.200  3.8  2.3

# string datetime
                    0    1   2   3   4   5   ...  10  11  12      13   14   15
0  2018/06/19 00:05:00  300   3   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0  18.100  3.8  2.3
1  2018/06/19 00:05:00  300   7   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0  16.700  3.8  2.3
2  2018/06/19 00:05:00  300   1   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0  17.387  3.8  2.3
3  2018/06/19 00:05:00  300   2   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0  16.200  3.8  2.3 
[4 rows x 16 columns]

# datetime converted
                   0    1   2   3   4   5   ...  10  11  12      13   14   15
0 2018-06-19 00:05:00  300   3   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0  18.100  3.8  2.3
1 2018-06-19 00:05:00  300   7   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0  16.700  3.8  2.3
2 2018-06-19 00:05:00  300   1   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0  17.387  3.8  2.3
3 2018-06-19 00:05:00  300   2   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0  16.200  3.8  2.3 
[4 rows x 16 columns]
```

---

Edit:

If you get errors when converting your `df[0]` you can use `pd.to_datetime(df[0], errors='coerce')` to coerce erroneous values to [`NaT`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html) - see the [documentation of pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer as it works very well until the end where `df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])` returns `ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '2018/06/17 Info')` however the `print(df)` command prints exactly the same table as you've shared.

Comment: @OrçunBaşlak  Your csv contains a `Info` somewhere inside your `df[0]` - `'2018/06/17 Info'` tells you as much - it is the value after glueing the filename to the current value of `df[0]` while still being a string. You cannot convert that into a meaningfull datetime . - you can use the parameter `errors='coerce'` to remove invaid entries when using `pd.to_datetime(df[0], errors='coerce')` - see [the docu](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: Thank you. I had some lines down in the file which I haven't checked. You answer works as intended. Thank you very much.